# Loud noise charging Macbook Pro USB-C

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, usb, charging

Anyone ever had a loud noise coming from the speakers when inserting the usb charger? When I say a loud noice, I mean a screeching, metal-scraping-like sound at full volume. My volume was turned off though. I keep getting the issue until I reboot my device.

System information:

- MacBook Pro (13-inch 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports)
- Processor: 3,1 GHz Intel Core i5
- Memory: 8GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650 1536 MB
- running macOS High Sierra (version 10.13.1)`

Comment: If it occurs while you have the volume turned off, it's an electrical issue. More than likely, there is a faulty component. You need to take it in for service.  You could start with an [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) to see if that has any effect.

Comment: This just happened to me, when I removed the charger from one port and plugged it into a different one. 15" 2016 model. Was so loud I peed a bit. That's all the diagnostic information I have, though.

Comment: I would also like to know if others have had this issue. I just plugged in my MacBook and it started screaming (not literally but the short burst of loud static did give me a little heart attack). I got so startled I took the charger out from the laptop immediately. When I plugged the charger back in nothing happened.

Comment: Same this just happened to me (MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports; 3.5 GHz Intel Core i7; 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3; Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650 1536 MB; volume muted). Sounded to me like the the normal tone you'd hear to indicate the battery is charging (with a lot of loud distortion).

Answer (score 2):

This is something you could record with a phone (or perhaps the Mac itself) and then open a support case directly with Apple. This sort of thing could be a firmware update needed or failing hardware, but I’d hesitate to speculate on the cause of this without hearing the sound, but I’m sure it’s disconcerting to say the least.

I would be sure to apply all system updates and possibly download the High Sierra installer and run it to be sure all firmware updates are applied on your Mac if opening a support case isn’t getting a quick response.

Comment: I've rebooted my device and since then (4 months ago) I haven't gotten the noise anymore. I just wondered what it was.