# Screeching Metallic Sound when plugging in USB-C Charging Cable

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, charging

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports), it happened twice this week now. I have a dongle with HDMI attached while plugging in my charging cable. My sound was muted.

The noise is uncomfortable and it gave me goosebumps. It's like two pieces of thin metallic plates were scratching each other at high speed. The screech was horrible. I'm not sure if the sound came from the speakers or the machine.

I found someone who've experienced this too.
-> [Loud noise charging Macbook Pro USB-C](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315485/loud-noise-charging-macbook-pro-usb-c?newreg=c6ac7744b29344ee8809ced22d2ec7b5)

Comment: Just had the same problem. Very unpleasant for me and my colleagues.

Comment: @Chucky I hope yours will stop. Mine never happened again. Also, I try not to plug in the charging USB-C cable through the 3-1 in one dongle. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same thing happen to me around July 2018 on a MBP 2017 15", this happened when I connected an AmazonBasics AV adaptor, I only own a couple of dongles, that one and the usb c to ethernet one from Amazon too, it has never happened again.

After it happened, I noticed that when using the internal speakers as soon (could be a few seconds) the audio reached a certain level, high sounds would be lost and audio would sound muffled.

It's on service now, they are replacing the top cover which houses the keyboard, battery, speakers and other components.